# wso2 identity server oauth authorization

Tags: oauth-2.0, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I`m trying to run playground2 example and authorize with WSO2 Identity server 5.0.0 using OAuth2. And when I choose the authorization_code grant type application failed to obtain token since identity server returns 401 error.
But with Identity Server 4.6.0 it works fine.

Authentication parameters is:

- grant_type: authorization_code
- client_id: XXXXXXX
- scope:
- callback url: http://localhost:8081/oauth2client
- authorize endpoint: https://localhost:9443/oauth2/authorize

Is it a bug of WSO2IS 5.0.0?

Answer (score 0):

Pls obtain the latest playground app from [this](http://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/branches/turing/products/is/5.0.0/modules/samples/oauth2/playground2/) location.

You call back url seems to be wrong. Please follow the steps given in [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/OpenID+Connect+with+the+WSO2+Identity+Server+and+WSO2+OAuth2+Playground) document which is explained for Identity Server 5.0.